# pip install django error using virtualenv

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv

I have set the virtual environment having

```
(website) username[`/public_html/website]
```

Have django project in `/public_html/website` directory

When i try to install django using `pip install django`
Gives following error

```
Collecting django 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions:)
No mathcing distribution for django
```

I have tried `which pip` it gives `public_html/website/bin/pip`

When I try `python manage.py runserver` Gives error `couldnt import django`

How should I install django in virtualenv and then runserver?

**EDIT**

When tried `pip search django` got the following error

```
HTTP error 403 while getting https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddhesh3186/public_html/website/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/siddhesh3186/public_html/website/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 45, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/home/siddhesh3186/public_html/website/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 62, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/home/siddhesh3186/.local/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1098, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/home/siddhesh3186/.local/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1437, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/home/siddhesh3186/public_html/website/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 776, in request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/siddhesh3186/public_html/website/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 862, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
```

This is the error I got

Comment: Update pip and try again
`pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`pip search django`. What does it show ?

*Edit:*

Try creating new virtual environment.
If problem still persist, create a virtual environment without pip
using `virtualenv --no-pip`, and then install pip using [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)

Comment: Edited Question